# How to re instantiate variables in try/catch block

Tags: java

I am working on a Cucumber test and I have the following:

```
        ResponseEntity<OrderGet> createResponse;
        try {
            createResponse = api.createAddress(headers, address);
        } catch (FeignException e) {
            System.out.println(e.status());
            scenarioContext.put("createResponseValidationCode", e.status());
            scenarioContext.put("createResponseValidation", createResponse);
        }
```

At the last line I get error for Intellij saying that `createResponse` might have not been initialized. When I initialize it with `null` and I add an `if ( .. != null)` it never executes it, it still remains null and does not re instantiate the variable. The line in the `try` block always throws exception. What approach should I use here?

Comment: If `createResponse` always throws an exception, why would you execute it again the catch block? It will fail again

Comment: @Ali can you explain why a singleton is relevant here? Or why this would loop.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't understand how this code works.

If the catch block executes, **that means the try block did not** (or did at most partially).

Specifically, if the catch block ends up being involved at all, that means 1 to n of all the statements of the try block have been executed so far, and the last statement executed (which does **NOT** have to be the last statement in the try block!) did not finish successfully.

Given that there's really only one invoke in your try block (which is invoking the `createAddress` method), that is the one that **DID NOT WORK**.

In other words, *there is no response object in the first place!* - and therefore, it is not possible to send a non-existent response. You have no instance of ResponseEntity. At all. Code failed before we got that far.

If you did this instead:

`ResponseEntity<OrderGet> createResponse = null;`

... then obviously in the catch block, createResponse would always remain null, and an if (x != null) deal in there would simply mean it would never trigger.

Put in simple terms: It's like this, you ask a baker to bake some bread.

Then the baker tells you: Aw, shoot, mate. I ran out of dough, sorry. You then go: That's no problem. Just give me the bread and I'll tell the client that asked me to get them some bread that this bread could not be baked. At which point the baker goes: You what, mate? **I don't have any bread**!